# Django - how to decrease DB queries when iterating

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a model `ProductFilter` in the project. An object of this model is a set of lookups defining a queryset. It's like a group of products - but just as a filter, not connected with a ForeignKey (ManyToManyField).

The product can be filtered in multiple `ProductFilter`s and the first is taken to account.

It works like this:

User define their filters. Then assign to each filter some pricing (and other) rules. 
For example filter with the name **"Products under 10 USD"** - rule - **increase the price by 10%**.

The problem is that when I render products or export them. I have to check for every product if they belong to any filter which means a lot of DB queries. There can be 100k products.

Do you have any ideas how to make it faster?

```
class Product(...):
    ...
    @property
    def price(self):
        for filter in self.user.filters():
            if filter.get_queryset().filter(pk=self.pk).exists():
                return filter.rule.apply_rule(self.price)


class ProductFilter(BaseTimeStampedModel):
    project = models.ForeignKey('projects.UserEshop', related_name='product_filters', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('FeedCategory', blank=True)
    brands = models.ManyToManyField('Brand', blank=True)
    manufacturers = models.ManyToManyField('Manufacturer', blank=True)
    import_price_no_vat_max = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=64, null=True, blank=True)
    import_price_no_vat_min = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=64, null=True, blank=True)
    name_icontains = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)


    def get_queryset(self):
         # products for this project
         qs = Product.objects.filter(source__user_eshop=self.project)
        if self.categories.exists():
            qs = qs.filter(category__in=self.categories.all().get_descendants(include_self=True))
        if self.brands.exists():
            qs = qs.filter(brand__in=self.brands.all())
        if self.manufacturers.exists():
            qs = qs.filter(manufacturer__in=self.manufacturers.all())
        if self.import_price_no_vat_max is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(import_price_no_vat__lte=self.import_price_no_vat_max)
        if self.import_price_no_vat_min is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(import_price_no_vat__gte=self.import_price_no_vat_min)
        if self.name_icontains:
            qs = qs.filter(name__icontains=self.name_icontains)
        return qs
```

**EDIT**

My best idea is to create a `ManyToManyField` on `ProductFilter` to `Product` and everytime somethings changes I'll assign products to every filter. I'm just not sure if `ManyToManyField` is ok to hold thousands or hundreds of thousands products.

Comment: Sure, I've had M:M association tables that have 10's of Million rows. The main question being is "products to every filter" actually appropriate or just easier for you to create> I'll grant the latter but not the former. That's the business rule to determine.

Comment: Are the filters going to be saved for future use? I don't really see the benefit of storing all these relationships in the database like this.